# how to add payment method to quickbooks through qbxml?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I'm using consolibyte php with web connector.I'm trying to create payment method add request using following xml.But i'm getting following error.but in quickbooks with that name no term existed.can you help any one?

3100: The name "cashondelivery" of the list element is already in use.

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="8.0"?>
    <QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <PaymentMethodAddRq>
    <PaymentMethodAdd>
    <Name>cashondelivery</Name>
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    <PaymentMethodType>AmericanExpress</PaymentMethodType>
    </PaymentMethodAdd>
    </PaymentMethodAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>';
    return $xml;
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that cashondelivery is already in QB.

Look for deleted entries as well. You might need to check the other lists and see if it is there.

Comment: its adding successfully to quickbooks but with error.